# Using baron solver in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I tried to solve an optimization problem given in pyomo examples using baron in Ubuntu (Linux).

Example problem:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()

model.x = Var(initialize=1.5)

model.y = Var(initialize=1.5)

def rosenbrock(model):

    return (1.0-model.x)**2 \

        + 100.0*(model.y - model.x**2)**2

model.obj = Objective(rule=rosenbrock, sense=minimize)

SolverFactory('baron').solve(model, tee=True)

model.pprint()
```

When I solve the above problem using Baron the following exception is thrown:

BARON version 19.3.24. Built: LNX-64 Sun Mar 24 16:49:54 EDT 2019

BARON is a product of The Optimization Firm.

For information on BARON, see https://minlp.com/about-baron

> Exception in thread Thread-23:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in
>   __bootstrap_inner
>
> ```
> self.run()
> ```
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
>
> ```
> self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyutilib/subprocess/processmngr.py",
>   line 367, in _merged_reader
>
> ```
> char = s.data.decode(encoding)
> ```
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>
> ```
> return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
> ```
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0:
>   unexpected end of data

When I solve the same problem using ipopt, the problem is solved as expected.

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Let me know if you need any further details.

Thanks in advance

Sakthi

Comment: What version of Pyomo are you using?

Comment: PYTHON VERSION - Python 2.7.15rc1

 PYOMO VERSION - Pyomo version 5.6.2

OS - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Linux)

Comment: Try updating to the most recent version of Pyomo.